# Wordpress image attachment

Tags: image, wordpress, attachment

I am using this code to get all posts attachment which it is doing fine.
My problem is I am not getting the desired attachment size. When I don't specify the size with "the_attachment_link($attachment->ID);" I get the thumbnail and when I try by adding "medium, small, large, or full" I get the full size only.
Am I missing something here? I need some support please.

```
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'numberposts' => null,
    'post_status' => null,
    'post_parent' => $post->ID
); 
$attachments = get_posts($args);
if ($attachments) {
foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
    echo apply_filters('the_title', $attachment->post_title);
    the_attachment_link($attachment->ID, 'medium', true);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi try something like this:

```
query_posts( array('post_type' => 'attachment','numberposts' => null,'post_status' => null,'post_parent' => $post->ID));
    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) :the_post(); 
            $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full');
    ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $src[0]; ?>" width="174px" height="142px" alt="" />                                
    <?php       
    endwhile; 
    else :          
        echo '<h3>Oops, something went wrong.</h3>';
    endif;
    wp_reset_query();
    ?>                      
    } ?>
```

make use of the $src[0].
set the height and width according to your preference.

hope this solves it.

Comment: thanks, but no luck. I am not even getting an image because the image's url is off (site.com/width='width')

Comment: I wasn't getting the desired image size because I set the sizes after the uploads. Should be code first then upload.

Comment: <?php
$images =& get_children('post_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image&post_parent=page_id_or_post_id_here' );
$counter=0;
foreach( (array) $images as $attachment_id => $attachment )
{[/code]
   $counter++;
echo apply_filters('the_title', $attachment->post_title);
echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, false );
 } 
?>
I ended up finding the above code if you want to retrieve image attachment for a specific page/post

Then go to library and attached any image to your post/page